# How can i create conditional column referring present columns of a dataframe and dictionary without using loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a datafarme

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"type":  ["A" ,"A1" ,"A" ,"A1","B" ],
                  "group":  ["g1", "g2","g2","g2","g1"]})
```

And i have a dictionary

```
 dic ={"AlphaA": {"A":  {"g1":"A_GRP1",  "g2":"A_GRP2"},
                  "A1": {"g1":"A1_GRP1", "g2":"A1_GRP2"}},
       "AlphaB": {"B":  {"g1":"B_GRP1",  "g2":"B_GRP2"}},
      }
```

i have to create a column name "value", which will use the data frame and dictionary and get value assigned to it

**Conditions to be applied:**

1. if type is "A" or "A1" it should refer dictionary key AlphaA and get the value for respective group and assign it to new column
2. if type is "B", it should refer dictionary key AlphaB and get the value of the respective group

**Example of row one:**
type is "A" hence refering dictionary key "AlphaA"
group is "g1
*therefore* :

```
dictt["AlphaA"]["A"]["g1"]          #would be the answer
```

**Required Output**

```
 final_df = pd.DataFrame({"type" :  ["A" ,"A1" ,"A" ,"A1","B" ],
                          "group":  ["g1", "g2","g2","g2","g1"],
                          "value":  ["A_GRP1", "A1_GRP2", "A_GRP2",
                                     "A1_GRP2", "B_GRP1"]})
```

I was able to achieve this using loops but its is taking lot of time,
hence looking for some speedy technique.

Comment: Performance is important? What is size of dictionary?

Comment: yeah performance is important beacuse i have to do it on somewhere 90k rows and dictionary has 2 keys and each keys have around 20 sub keys and every sub key has 3 values @jezrael

Comment: sure, i ll do that and let you know. Thanks @jezrael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `dic` the input dictionary, you can merge the dictionary values into a single dictionary (with help of [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap)), convert to DataFrame and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to Series and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```py
from collections import ChainMap
s = pd.DataFrame(dict(ChainMap(*dic.values()))).unstack()

# without ChainMap
# d = {k: v for d in dic.values() for k,v in d.items()}
# pd.DataFrame(d).unstack()

out = df.merge(s.rename('value'), left_on=['type', 'group'], right_index=True)
```

output:

```
  type group    value
0    A    g1   A_GRP1
1   A1    g2  A1_GRP2
3   A1    g2  A1_GRP2
2    A    g2   A_GRP2
4    B    g1   B_GRP1
```

Comment: Chainmap convenience is sometimes negated by its relative slow speed...sometimes ...

Comment: @sammywemmy yes, that's why I also provided a list comprehension alternative. It should not be used on very large dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with Series created from dictionary by dict comprehension:

```
d1 = {(k1, k2): v2 for k, v in d.items() for k1, v1 in v.items() for k2, v2 in v1.items()}
df = df.join(pd.Series(d1).rename('value'), on=['type','group'])
print (df)
  type group    value
0    A    g1   A_GRP1
1   A1    g2  A1_GRP2
2    A    g2   A_GRP2
3   A1    g2  A1_GRP2
4    B    g1   B_GRP1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the outer key of original dictionary and try apply on rows

```py
d = {k:v for vs in d.values() for k, v in vs.items()}
df['value'] = (df.assign(value=df['type'].map(d))
               .apply(lambda row: row['value'][row['group']], axis=1)
               )
```

```
print(d)

{'A': {'g1': 'A_GRP1', 'g2': 'A_GRP2'}, 'A1': {'g1': 'A1_GRP1', 'g2': 'A1_GRP2'}, 'B': {'g1': 'B_GRP1', 'g2': 'B_GRP2'}}

print(df)

  type group    value
0    A    g1   A_GRP1
1   A1    g2  A1_GRP2
2    A    g2   A_GRP2
3   A1    g2  A1_GRP2
4    B    g1   B_GRP1
```